# How to detect lines using houghlines on the actual image rather than in the hough graph

Tags: matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I want to detect lines in a text document. Here is the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdDX1.jpg) this was eroded to make the task of edge detection easier using the `erode` function. Here is the [eroded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3dzr.jpg).

Now to detect the lines I used `houghlines`, and used the following code in my script file.

```
I  = imread('c:\new.jpg');
rotI = imrotate(I,33,'crop');
bw_I = rgb2gray(rotI);
BW = edge(bw_I,'canny');
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
imshow(H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,...
            'InitialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho');
axis on, axis normal, hold on;
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
plot(x,y,'s','color','white');
% Find lines and plot them
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow(rotI), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end

% highlight the longest line segment
plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
```

This produced [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whzxd.jpg). Now I know that the intersecting points are the detected lines. What I want is to somehow show these lines detected onto the original image such as highlighting lines or underlining them. Is this possible? Which function would I use for that?

edit: What I wanted to say was that how do I translate the detected lines( intersecting points) from the last result to a more clearer result.

Comment: What are you problems? You can't convert coordinates of Hough peaks into line parameters? Maybe, you will read wikipedia?

Comment: The last plot highlights detected lines with a certain angle (x-axis) and at a certain distance to the center of the image. Based on this information (angle and starting point), you can create lines and draw them. [This question/answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/17086) may be helpful.

Comment: [This part of the Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/analyzing-images.html#f11-27827) seems to explain exactly how to do what it is you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply `imshow` to the results of the `edge` function-call.

[This part of the Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/analyzing-images.html#f11-27827) explains what you are trying to accomplish:

1. Read an image into the MATLAB workspace.

   ```
   I  = imread('circuit.tif');
   ```
2. For this example, rotate and crop the image using the [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) function.

   ```
   rotI = imrotate(I,33,'crop');
   fig1 = imshow(rotI);
   ```
3. Find the edges in the image using the [`edge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html) function.

   ```
   BW = edge(rotI,'canny');
   figure, imshow(BW);
   ```

It is this 3rd step you are after. You already ran the `edge` function.
Now, all that remains is visualizing the results `BW` with [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html?searchHighlight=imshow).